# On the geometrical form of the Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I'm currently working on the geometrical form of Hahn-Banach theorem:

> **Hahn-Banach, first geometric form** Let  $A \subset E$  and $B \subset E$  be two nonempty convex subsets such that $A \cap B=\emptyset$. Assume that one of them is open. Then there
> exists a closed hyperplane that separates $ A$ and $B$.

In the proof, it is used that $A-B$ is convex. I wonder if we may construct two non-convex sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A-B$ is convex.

Edit: Sorry, I forget to precise that $A\cap B= \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbf{R}^2$ it holds that $S^1-S^1=B_2(0)$

Comment: the condition $A\cap B= \emptyset$  is supposed.

Comment: If $|v|>2$ then $(S^1+v)-S^1= B_2(0)+v$ and $(S^1+v)\cap S^1=\emptyset$